# What's the procedure for achieving Irish Tourist visa for spouse of Irish resident?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, ireland

I will be relocating to Dublin, Ireland on employment visa with a Critical Skill Employment Permit. My wife, who is a Bangladeshi passport holder, needs a visa to enter Ireland. We couldn't apply for the spouse visa for her as she will not be able to live long-term, but our plan is to arrange a travel visa for her on my sponsorship.

Please note, Bangladesh doesn't have an Irish visa consulate.

Can someone please let me know what is the fastest and most convenient way to arrange the visa for her?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Critical Skill Visas are only for non EU citizens hence freedom of movement does not apply. She needs to send her passport and documents to New Delhi for processing as far as I can tell from Google. Apparently you don't need to apply in person.

Comment: That is if she lives in Bangladesh. Otherwise she should apply at the Irish Embassy where she is resident.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Bangladesh.

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://www.vfsglobalirelandvisa.com/india/pdf/Bangladesh.pdf Bangladeshis can apply through the VFS application centre in Kolkata